# Minimum ordering of a loop of values

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph

Given a sequence like:

```
1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,3
```

What is an **efficient** way to obtain the minimum ordering:

```
1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2
```

The brute force approach is obvious so please don't recommend it -- unless to provide a convincing proof that the brute force approach is the only way to do it!

**More detail**

I have an algorithm that generates a list of numbers. The output of the algorithm is a list / array, but logically the numbers represent a loop, where only the relative order of the elements matters. In order to store these loops for later comparison I want to put store them in such a way that the one-dimensional list of numbers stored represents the minimum ordering of the elements in the loop. A picture would be most helpful:

[image: Loop]

This loop describes the path around the T tetromino, where 1 is move forward, 2 is turn right, and 3 is turn left. It doesn't matter where you start or even which direction you go, following this sequence of 18 moves will get you a T tetromino. The output of the algorithm which produces this loop will return the elements with an arbitrary starting point and direction. So the returned array could be:

**Arbitrary initial ordering:**

```
1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,3
```

[image: Arbitrary order]

There is one minimum ordering, though. It can be obtained from two different circuits, reflecting the fact that the T tetromino is symmetrical:

**Minimum ordering:**

```
1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2
```

[image: Minimum order]

**Brute force**

The obvious brute force method is to construct all possible orderings and take the minimum. My question is whether there is a more clever and efficient way of doing this.

Comment: This is a well-studied problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation (simply apply it twice and take the min of those to look at "backwards" too)

Comment: @harold Thanks! I lacked the vocabulary or background to even know how to search for that answer. Post that link as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well-studied problem called the [lexicographically minimal string rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation).

The better algorithms all run in O(n) time as opposed to O(n*n) for the naive algorithm.